# Does using Enum as a fully featured object which makes use of dynamic dispatch like in this case mean misusing it or not a good design?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums, polymorphism

I have implemented a Role Enum which contains role definitions with ranks. For the `getAssignableRoles()` part, my colleague says that this is misusing the Enum or over engineering and states that it is not readable with this form.

```
public enum Role {
    USER("ROLE_user", 1),
    CUSTOMER("ROLE_customer", 2),
    PRODUCT_OWNER("ROLE_product_manager", 3) {
        @Override
        public List<Role> getAssignableRoles() {
            return getLowerRankedRoles().stream().filter(e -> !e.equals(CUSTOMER_ADMIN)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    },
    CUSTOMER_ADMIN("ROLE_customer_admin", 3) { 
        @Override
        public List<Role> getAssignableRoles() {
            return getLowerRankedRoles().stream().filter(e -> !e.equals(PRODUCT_OWNER)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    },
    USER_MANAGER("ROLE_user_manager", 5),
    ADMIN("ROLE_admin", 99);

    private final String value;
    private final int rank;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    Role(String value, int rank) {
        this.value = value;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public static Role findByAbbr(String abbr) {
        return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(value -> value.value.equals(abbr)).findFirst().orElse(UNKNOWN);
    }

    public String getExactValue() {
        return value.replaceFirst("^ROLE_", "");
    }

    // Each role has a distinct grant rank but for some roles even if they have same grant level their role assigning changes in the context.
    public List<Role> getAssignableRoles() {
        return getLowerRankedRoles();
    }

    protected List<Role> getLowerRankedRoles() {
        return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(value -> value.rank <= rank).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static Predicate<String> isInRealm() {
         return (String role) -> (Arrays.stream(values()).anyMatch(value -> value.value.equals(role)));
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do was, in the client code to be able to call it like

```
Role.findByAbbr(role).getAssignableRoles()
```

Is using Enums like that is a good practice or design? Can we get most of dynamic dispatch features from Enum?

Comment: Since this code works, it seems more fitting on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is actually more interesting than it seems at first sight. I see two different points here:

1. Your roles don't have mutable state;
2. You need to access the list of all different roles, which is fixed.

Talking about point (1), if a value is not mutable then is called *constant* and Java `enum`s are exactly this: sets of constant values ([see the official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)).

Point (2) refers to the power of the `values()` predefined method of Java `enum`s. In fact the implementation of  `Role.findByAbbr(abbr)` would be a mess using other strategies.

Let me elaborate on this a little further. If you don't want the client code to be able to create new roles a common strategy would be to exploit the *package-friendly* visibility scope. Declare an abstract class `Role` inside the package `com.example.role`.

```java
package com.example.role;

public abstract class Role {
    private int rank;
    private String value;

    Role(String value, int rank) {
        this.value = value;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```

Note that there is no explicit visibility modifier on the constructor (so it's package-friendly). Only classes inside the same package can call class `Role`'s constructor, hence inheritance is possible only inside the same package***.

```java
package com.example.role;

public class UserRole extends Role {
    private static final UserRole instance = new UserRole();

    private UserRole() {
        super("ROLE_user", 1);
    }

    public UserRole getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

We are trying to simulate your `enum` using plain Java classes so we also used the singleton pattern to have a single instance of each role.

Everything was pretty easy, but when it comes to the `values()` predefined method the story changes.

```java
package com.example.role;

public final class Roles {
    private static Collection<Role> values = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(
        UserRole.getInstance(),
        CustomerRole.getInstance(),
        ProductOwnerRole.getInstance(),
        CustomerAdminRole.getInstance(),
        UserManagerRole.getInstance(),
        AdminRole.getInstance()));

    private Roles() {
    }

    public static Collection<Role> values() {
        return values;
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```

Everytime you add a new `Role` you have to remember to add it to the `values` list. That's ugly.

The interface for the client code would still be pretty, like the following:

```java
Collection<Role> assignables = Roles.getAssignableRolesFor(role);
```

In conclusion, your exploit of `enum`'s properties doesn't look so bad. Your roles are constants and the predefined `values()` method gives you a lot of power out of the box. Having all the ranks and names in a single place and not scattered across multiple files is also really nice.

---

*** A user could potentially create a package with the same name inside his client code and create a new `Role`, but this is a bad practice and I won't even consider.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good or bad in general. The answer depends on your goals.

If you want to prohibit creation of other instances of this type with other parameters, this can be fine. If you want that administrators in your system create new roles *dynamically*, then you cannot realize it with such design.

If you are sure you will not change behaviour later on, then such design is good.

If you want that behaviour of the *Role* can be extended or modified for different use cases (e.g. in one use case you get requirement that role support multiple abbreviations, in another use case you get requirements that abbreviations must be case insensitive), then you cannot realize it because enumeration is final, it cannot have subclasses. For each new requirement you will have to change this enumeration. With the time it will be hard to do: If you change it for one use case, you can break another use case.